# Whenever I try to use @jit on my class method, I get IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python, jit, numba

I've been trying for several days to get `@jit` working to speed up my code.
Finally I came across this, describing adding `@jit` to object methods:
http://williamjshipman.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/learning-python-eight-ways-to-filter-an-image

I have a class called `GentleBoostC` and I want to speed up the method within it that's called `train`.
`train` accepts three arguments (a 2D array, a 1D array, and an integer), and returns nothing.

This is what I have in code:

```
import numba
from numba import jit, autojit, int_, void, float_, object_


class GentleBoostC(object):
    # lots of functions

    # and now the function I want to speed up
    @jit (void(object_,float_[:,:],int_[:],int_)) 
    def train(self, X, y, H):
        # do stuff
```

But I keep getting an indentation error, pointing to the line that defines the train function. There is nothing wrong with my indents. I have re-indented my entire code. And if I comment out the line with `@jit`, then there are no problems.

Here's the exact error:

```
   @jit (void(object_,float_[:,:],int_[:],int_))
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py", line 224, in _jit_decorator
    nopython=nopython, func_ast=func_ast, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py", line 133, in compile_function
    func_env = pipeline.compile2(env, func, restype, argtypes, func_ast=func_ast, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\pipeline.py", line 133, in compile2
    func_ast = functions._get_ast(func)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\functions.py", line 89, in _get_ast
    ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST | flags, True)
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gentleboost_c_class_jit_v5_nolimit.py", line 1
    def train(self, X, y, H):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Run your script with `python -tt`. You probably **do** have indentation problems. And what does `cat -eT filename.py` show? Look at both the `@jit` line and the surrounding context.

Comment: Then why does it work with no issues at all when I comment out the @jit line? Anyway, how can I use python -tt? I'm running python using Anaconda's Spyder - how would I do it from there?

Comment: Two options: either the `@jit` line mixes tabs and spaces inconsistent with the other lines, or you are using an ancient Python version that doesn't yet support decorators.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Is my @jit line correct though?

Comment: Note that you didn't include the full error message, so I am making (educated) guesses here. I could be guessing wrong, so please do include the full error message.

Comment: I have not used that specific decorator, but the *syntax* looks fine.

Comment: Just edited the question to add the error. Also, I've copy-pasted the whitespace on the @jit line and other method definition lines and pasted it before def train(...)

Comment: Ah, interesting, the `@jit` decorator tries to compile the code. I suspect now that it doesn't support *methods*, only top-level *functions*.

Comment: I cannot find anything specific in the documentation about methods, but all examples are applied to *functions* only (outside a class context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see from the documentation, you *cannot* apply the decorator to a method; the error you see is from the JIT parser not handling the source code indentation when not in the context of a `class` statement.

If you want the body of that method to be compiled, you'll need to factor it out to a separate function, and call that function from the method:

```
@jit(void(object_, float_[:,:], int_[:], int_)) 
def train_function(instance, X, y, H):
    # do stuff

class GentleBoostC(object):
    def train(self, X, y, H):
        train_function(self, X, y, H)
```

Comment: But the train method accesses many class data members, and it affects existing members... so does this mean I would need to pass them all as parameters and then return the affected things as well?

Comment: @user961627: That's why the `train_function` function accepts an `instance` first argument. It is the same object as `self`, I justs chose a different name to distinguish it from the common convention for the first arguments of methods.

Comment: There's a follow up issue now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685916/cannot-coerce-to-or-from-object-in-nopython-context-error-after-python... does have anything to do with limited support for objects or something?

Comment: To keep the function within the class body, one can make it a static method of the class, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52722636