# TypeError: Arrays must have consistent types in assignment

Tags: python, numpy, types, numba, numba-pro

Following up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683592/whenever-i-try-to-use-jit-on-my-class-method-i-get-indentationerror-unexpecte/25683973?noredirect=1#comment40140761_25683973), I've got code like the following:

```
@jit(float_[:,:,:](float_[:,:], int_[:], int_)) 
def train_function(X, y, H):
    # do lots of stuff, including setting the arrays g and g_per_round like this:
    g = np.zeros((no_features, no_classes))
    g_per_round = np.zeros((H, no_features, no_classes))

    # do more stuff, then:    
        g_h = None
        j = 0
        print "Calculating regression coefficients per class. .."
        # building the parameters per j class
        for y1_w in zip(z.T, weights.T):
            y1, w = y1_w 
            temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, X, w).fit()  # Step 2(a)(ii)
            if g_h is None: # sometimes g *is* None, and that's fine
                   g_h = temp_g.params # this is an array of floats
            else:
                    g_h = np.c_[g_h, temp_g.params]
            j = j + 1

        if np.allclose(g,0) or g is None:
            g = g_h
        else:            
            g = g + g_h 

    # do lots more stuff, then finally:
    return g_per_round

class GentleBoostC(object):
    # init functions and stuff
    def train(self, X, y, H):
        self.g_per_round = train_function(X, y, H)
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
 @jit(float_[:,:,:](float_[:,:], int_[:], int_))
 more lines, etc etc etc, last few lines:
    unresolved_types, var_name)
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\typesystem\ssatypes.py", line 767, in promote_arrays
    assert_equal(non_array_types[0])
  File "C:\Users\app\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\typesystem\ssatypes.py", line 764, in assert_equal
    var_name, result_type, other_type))
TypeError: Arrays must have consistent types in assignment for variable 'g': 'float64[:, :]' and 'none'
```

I actually had no issues with this before trying to add `@jit` to speed up my code.

Comment: Looks like `g_h` is `None`. It's possible that if your `for` loop never gets entered, then `g_h` will not get set to anything.

Comment: Why don't you output `z` or `weights`? If either of these is empty, then your `for` loop will never be entered.

Comment: I just edited the code to assign g some value when it's none. Also - I did try outputting weights and z, but the thing is - these aren't run time errors. I think these are compile errors from the numba package, even before the code starts running. The problem I think is in assigning a variable that's None to a variable that isn't None. Isn't there anyway around that in Numba?

Comment: Ahh I understand. Try initializing `g_h` to `np.zeroes` instead of `None`.

Comment: that was it! Thanks. You can put that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Numba is inferring `g_h` to be `NoneType`; initialize it to a vector and it will compile it properly:

```
g_h = np.zeroes((H, no_features, no_classes))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that numba cannot know that `g_h` will not be `None` when it is finally assigned to `g` because the type of `g_h` depends on runtime flow control. In other words, if `g_h` *could ever not be* a float64, then it has to assume that sometimes isn't.

This is a [documented limitation of numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.13.4/types.html) and a limitation of type inference systems in general:

> However, there are some restrictions, namely that variables must have
>   a unifyable type at control flow merge points. For example, the
>   following code will not compile:
>
> ```
> @jit def incompatible_types(arg):
>     if arg > 10:
>         x = "hello"
>     else:
>         x = 1
>
>     return x        # ERROR! Inconsistent type for x!
> ```

The solution is to initialize `g_h` to a compatible type instead of `= None`.

Numba's type inference is actually quite smart so you can mix types on a particular local variable without problems in many cases as long as the type can be unified before return. Read [Numba documentation on types](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.13.4/types.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! If you have any experience with Numba, do you have any idea about this follow-up  problem: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/25685916/cannot-coerce-to-or-from-object-in-nopython-context-error-after-python