# Why a njit function doesn't works when it's inside a class but work when it's outside?

Tags: python, numba

I don't understand why the function `compute` works when it is outside of the the class `myclass` but doesn't works when it is inside?

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def compute(length):
    x=np.zeros(length)
    for i in range(length):
        x[i] = i
    return x

class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 100

    def Simule(self):
        res = compute(self.length)
        print(res)

    def Simule2(self):
        res = self.compute(self.length)
        print(res)

    @njit
    def compute(self, length):
        x = np.zeros(length)
        for i in range(length):
            x[i] = i
        return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = myclass()
    instance.Simule()
    instance.Simule2()
```

Comment: This was previosly answered by [How do I use numba on a member function of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769100/how-do-i-use-numba-on-a-member-function-of-a-class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use numba on a member function of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769100/how-do-i-use-numba-on-a-member-function-of-a-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this decorator doesn't recognize if a decorated callabe is function or method, you can change it to be a staticmethod:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def compute(length):
    x=np.zeros(length)
    for i in range(length):
        x[i] = i
    return x

class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 100

    def Simule(self):
        res = compute(self.length)
        print(res)

    def Simule2(self):
        res = self.compute(self.length)
        print(res)

    @staticmethod
    @njit
    def compute(length):
        x = np.zeros(length)
        for i in range(length):
            x[i] = i
        return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = myclass()
    instance.Simule()
    instance.Simule2()
```